# Replacing property placeholders in arbitrary (json) files in a spring app

Tags: java, spring

I have spring application that get bunch of configs from JSON files. Some of the JSON attributes will be different in different environments. Is there a way I can use spring placeholders in JSON files and have spring resolve those at application start up?

Comment: Hi @Pushkar, were you able to find a way around this? Please let me know